# MDX - How to "Summarize" a Filtered result set

Tags: filter, aggregate, mdx

i'm struggling to determine the proper MDX query syntax in order to return the expected result set after moving the filters in order to support advanced nested filtering.

The query below is what is being generated today and the screenshot shows the results. Does anyone have any insights as to how to get the results needed as described in the screenshot based on the query below.

Note - i believe the Filters need to stay where they are in order to support nested complex filters. i.e. ((A=1 OR B<1) AND (A>1 OR C=2)) || (B=3 AND C=4)

```
  WITH
  SET AllRowsSet AS
    {
      Filter
      (
        NonEmpty
        (
            called_cities.[called_city].Children*
            called_countries.[called_country_name].Children*
            billing_months.[billing_month].Children*
            sources_pivot_v1.[source_name_l1].Children*
            products_pivot.[product_name_l1].Children*
            products_pivot.[product_name_l2].Children
            ,{
                [Measures].[actual_duration]
                ,[Measures].[amount]
            }
        )
       ,
        billing_months.[billing_month].CurrentMember.Member_Caption = '201805'
        AND products_pivot.[product_name_l1].CurrentMember.Member_Caption = 'Usage'
        AND products_pivot.[product_name_l2].CurrentMember.Member_Caption = 'LD International'
        AND called_countries.[called_country_name].CurrentMember.Member_Caption <> 'TEST_NULL'
        AND (
            sources_pivot_v1.[source_name_l1].CurrentMember.Member_Caption = 'Company for Joint'
            OR sources_pivot_v1.[source_name_l1].CurrentMember.Member_Caption = 'Cisco Call Manager'
        )
      )
    }
  MEMBER [Measures].totalrows AS AllRowsSet.Count
  MEMBER [Measures].[called_city] AS called_cities.[called_city].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
  MEMBER [Measures].[called_country_name] AS called_countries.[called_country_name].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
  MEMBER [Measures].[billing_month] AS billing_months.[billing_month].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
  MEMBER [Measures].[source_name_l1] AS sources_pivot_v1.[source_name_l1].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
  MEMBER [Measures].[product_name_l1] AS products_pivot.[product_name_l1].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
  MEMBER [Measures].[product_name_l2] AS products_pivot.[product_name_l2].CurrentMember.Member_Caption

SELECT
  {
    [Measures].[actual_duration]
   ,[Measures].[amount]
   ,[Measures].totalrows
   ,[Measures].[called_city]
   ,[Measures].[called_country_name]
   ,[Measures].[billing_month]
   ,[Measures].[source_name_l1]
   ,[Measures].[product_name_l1]
   ,[Measures].[product_name_l2]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,SubSet
  (
    Order
    (
      Filter
      (
        NonEmpty
        (
            called_cities.[called_city].Children*
            called_countries.[called_country_name].Children*
            billing_months.[billing_month].Children*
            sources_pivot_v1.[source_name_l1].Children*
            products_pivot.[product_name_l1].Children*
            products_pivot.[product_name_l2].Children
         ,{
            [Measures].[actual_duration]
           ,[Measures].[amount]
          }
        )
       ,
        billing_months.[billing_month].CurrentMember.Member_Caption = '201805'
        AND products_pivot.[product_name_l1].CurrentMember.Member_Caption = 'Usage'
        AND products_pivot.[product_name_l2].CurrentMember.Member_Caption = 'LD International'
        AND called_countries.[called_country_name].CurrentMember.Member_Caption <> 'TEST_NULL'
        AND (
            sources_pivot_v1.[source_name_l1].CurrentMember.Member_Caption = 'Company for Joint'
            OR sources_pivot_v1.[source_name_l1].CurrentMember.Member_Caption = 'Cisco Call Manager'
        )
      )
     ,[Measures].[amount]
     ,BDESC
    )
   ,0
   ,250
  ) ON ROWS
FROM
(
  SELECT {billing_months.[v1_disabled].[v1_disabled].&[0]} ON 0 FROM calls
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To aggregate you can - 
1. Move the ON ROWS set into the WITH clause
2. Wrap it in the Aggregate
3. You will need to find a 'spare' dimension in your cube that is not being used in this query to create this new custom MEMBER:

```
WITH
  SET AllRowsSet AS
    {
      Filter
      (
        NonEmpty
        (
            called_cities.[called_city].Children*
            called_countries.[called_country_name].Children*
            billing_months.[billing_month].Children*
            sources_pivot_v1.[source_name_l1].Children*
            products_pivot.[product_name_l1].Children*
            products_pivot.[product_name_l2].Children
            ,{
                [Measures].[actual_duration]
                ,[Measures].[amount]
            }
        )
       ,
        billing_months.[billing_month].CurrentMember.Member_Caption = '201805'
        AND products_pivot.[product_name_l1].CurrentMember.Member_Caption = 'Usage'
        AND products_pivot.[product_name_l2].CurrentMember.Member_Caption = 'LD International'
        AND called_countries.[called_country_name].CurrentMember.Member_Caption <> 'TEST_NULL'
        AND (
            sources_pivot_v1.[source_name_l1].CurrentMember.Member_Caption = 'Company for Joint'
            OR sources_pivot_v1.[source_name_l1].CurrentMember.Member_Caption = 'Cisco Call Manager'
        )
      )
    }
  MEMBER [Measures].totalrows AS AllRowsSet.Count
  MEMBER [Measures].[called_city] AS called_cities.[called_city].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
  MEMBER [Measures].[called_country_name] AS called_countries.[called_country_name].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
  MEMBER [Measures].[billing_month] AS billing_months.[billing_month].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
  MEMBER [Measures].[source_name_l1] AS sources_pivot_v1.[source_name_l1].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
  MEMBER [Measures].[product_name_l1] AS products_pivot.[product_name_l1].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
  MEMBER [Measures].[product_name_l2] AS products_pivot.[product_name_l2].CurrentMember.Member_Caption

MEMBER [SpareDimension].[SpareHierarchy].[myAggregation] AS   //<< REPLACE <[SpareDimension].[SpareHierarchy]> WITH A VALID DIMENSION/HIERARCHY IN YOUR CUBE THAT IS NOT BEING USED IN THE SCRIPT
Aggregate(
SubSet
  (
    Order
    (
      Filter
      (
        NonEmpty
        (
            called_cities.[called_city].Children*
            called_countries.[called_country_name].Children*
            billing_months.[billing_month].Children*
            sources_pivot_v1.[source_name_l1].Children*
            products_pivot.[product_name_l1].Children*
            products_pivot.[product_name_l2].Children
         ,{
            [Measures].[actual_duration]
           ,[Measures].[amount]
          }
        )
       ,
        billing_months.[billing_month].CurrentMember.Member_Caption = '201805'
        AND products_pivot.[product_name_l1].CurrentMember.Member_Caption = 'Usage'
        AND products_pivot.[product_name_l2].CurrentMember.Member_Caption = 'LD International'
        AND called_countries.[called_country_name].CurrentMember.Member_Caption <> 'TEST_NULL'
        AND (
            sources_pivot_v1.[source_name_l1].CurrentMember.Member_Caption = 'Company for Joint'
            OR sources_pivot_v1.[source_name_l1].CurrentMember.Member_Caption = 'Cisco Call Manager'
        )
      )
     ,[Measures].[amount]
     ,BDESC
    )
   ,0
   ,250
  )
)
SELECT
  {
    [Measures].[actual_duration]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,[SpareDimension].[SpareHierarchy].[myAggregation] ON ROWS
FROM
(
  SELECT {billing_months.[v1_disabled].[v1_disabled].&[0]} ON 0 FROM calls
);
```